# sync normalize tables vs json table in postgresql, so i can use graphql and sql, future neo4j

Tags: postgresql, neo4j

I have not found real sync from postgreSql to new graph database like  neo4j, so I've decide to use same postgresql to sync one normalise tables with json table on the same postgresql with a differenta name for a database. So i have the best of two worlds, sql and nosql database.
When i see sql is more fast than graphql i can choose, and in the future, when i moved the nosql tables to a real graph database like neo4j and i ll be able to sync, i dont need to change the app that can use both database synced

Someone did already this? or it's a dumm  idea? Or someone already use automatic libraries to sync from postgresql to neo4j  ? and the another sens too ? or must I write sync scripts from scratch if i want to sync two databases?

Comment: It's not strange, when you producte a *big* application or platform, to use more than one tool. You don't normally need to have *absolutely everything* on both tables. A graph is good for representing and traversing entity-entity-relationships, that would require recursive queries in SQL, and it's got built-in algorithms for shortest paths and the like. You normally store *that* information in the graph, and all the information that would benefit from a *relational* model on the RDBMS (normally SQL) part.

Comment: thanks @joanolo, i'd like to know how to do the companies to sync databases? every one write their own sync programm?

Comment: It's normally done at the `application layer` or through some `middleware`, mostly developed in-house. When you reach the complexity point to need simultaneously *relational* and *graph*, you aren't usually *smallish*. If you need it just for specific analysis, you have one DB (normally the SQL one) to be the reference, and export into the other the needed data. It's not that different from a *data warehouse* scenario.

Comment: can I use node and js for all my middleware? it's the best language?

Comment: There's not a single answer for that. Does your team know the framework well enough? Does it provide the right connectors to the databases you intend to you? Is it performant engough? Do you have the rigth development (configuring, programming, debugging, controlling versions, deploying, ...) tools?

Comment: we can choose only betweeh php and nodejs... have you worked in sync databases like nosql?